# fluentd localtime is working for stdout, but not elasticsearch

Tags: fluentd

I'm tailing a syslog file which doesn't have the timezone. By default fluentd (incorrectly) assumes the timezone is UTC, so it shifts the time off by several hours.

I can fix this for stdout, using 'localtime true', but I can't   find a setting to do the same thing for elasticsearch:

```
<source>
  @type tail
#  read_from_head true
  <parse>
    @type syslog
  </parse>
  path /tmp/syslog
  pos_file /tmp/var_log_syslog.pos
  tag syslog.file
</source>
<match syslog.**>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type elasticsearch
    host elasticsearch
    port 9200
    logstash_format true
    logstash_prefix fluentd
    logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
    include_tag_key true
    type_name access_log
    tag_key @log_name
    flush_interval 1s
    utc_index false
  </store>
  <store>
    @type stdout
    localtime true
  </store>
</match>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the desired behavior is the default behavior. Fluentd seems to use the localtime zone, but I was running it in a docker container and I forgot to set the container's timezone.